# How to add a column with predetermined values into my matrix visual?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm hoping you can help guide me in the right direction or point me towards some YouTube videos.

I am using calculated groups to produce a matrix visual which looks something like this:

| Measure | MTD | YTD | Projected 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Measure 1 | 5 | 30 | 72 |
| Measure 2 | 8 | 57 | 137 |
| Measure 3 | 2 | 65 | 156 |

What I'd like to add is a 2023 Target column for each of the measures. The measure targets sit in a standalone table and they are just predetermined values. How would I go about importing these values into my matrix visual? Also, how would I go about utilising the values from this newly added column to determine the variance between 2023 Projected and 2023 Target? I'd like my matrix to look like this:

| Measure | MTD | YTD | Projected 2023 | Target 2023 | 2023 Projected minus Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Measure 1 | 5 | 30 | 72 | 70 | 2 |
| Measure 2 | 8 | 57 | 137 | 120 | 17 |
| Measure 3 | 2 | 65 | 156 | 150 | 6 |

Comment: First add some sample data in tabular format, then show your expected output with code so far you have tried with.

Comment: Thank you, @mkRabbani. I've added some sample data in tabular format. I guess my question is, how do I get the predetermined Target 2023 values to be picked up and displayed into column Target 2023? And then how do I reference it to arrive at the last column (2023 Projected minus Target)